# Element displays "none" when window is smaller than element's width.

Tags: css, class, hide, hidden, inherited

I'm wrestling with a Tumblr theme's CSS. I have a section class in the header div:

```
#header .header .content{
position:relative;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0 2.5rem
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The section hides when the window is 1px smaller than the section's *INHERITED WIDTH* (516px, from Chrome dev tools). This is not a problem on desktop, but I need it to stay visible on mobile, ideally at 100% width + padding and relative margins.

1) I know it is not a Media Query, because the only @media queries are set at different values than this inherited width. Further, when I define the section's width absolutely, it hides at the newly defined width.

2) When I change display property from inline-block to anything else, it hides the section completely, at any window size.

3) The header div remains intact. Only the section hides.

4) I have scoured the linked js and other css looking for anything that might be affecting the class, but nothing was found.

Please help! Thank you!!!

Comment: I don't know if I could answer, but I do see no semicolon on the padding property...

Comment: The only things that can affect an element is CSS media queries or Javascript resize event listeners.  You must have missed one and without access to the entire code base we can't help you here :)

Comment: Thanks guys. @MarshallOfSound What would a JS resize event listener look like?